# ASC/DESC sorting in MS Access

Tags: vba, sorting, ms-access, columnsorting

I have a table like this:

```
Name     Country      Grade
Lily     Germany      A
Anna     USA          C
Leon     Slovenia     -
Mia      Italy        
Carlos   Mexico       B
```

And have two buttons:

```
1. ASC button
2. DESC button
```

I am trying that the buttons sort the table in asc/desc order but the problem is that i have A,B,C letters but are actually grades. With my code:

```
Private Sub cboAufS_Click()

If Me.cboFilData = "KK" Then
        Me.Text1163.SetFocus
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSortAscending
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub cboAbS_Click()
If Me.cboFilData = "KK" Then
        Me.Text1163.SetFocus
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSortDescending
    End If
End Sub
```

This code gives me the wrong results, for ASC i get : " ", -, A, B, C and need " ", - C, B, A, and for DESC i get C, B, A, -, " " and i need A, B, C, -, " "

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Calculate a field in query to apply sorting on and use that query as form or report RecordSource.

```
Switch(Grade="A",5, Grade="B",4, Grade="C",3, Grade="-",2, True,1) AS SortOrd
```

In a form, use code in button events like:

```
Me.OrderBy = "SortOrd ASC"
```

or

```
Me.OrderBy = "SortOrd DESC"
```

In a simple report, similar code can be used to dynamically set sort order. Code for complex report that uses Sorting & Grouping utility in design will be more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query:

```sql
SELECT 
    Table1.Name, 
    Table1.Country, 
    Table1.Grade
FROM 
    Table1
ORDER BY 
    Abs(Nz([Grade]) = "") DESC, 
    Abs([Grade] = "-") DESC, 
    Table1.Grade DESC;
```

Replace DESC with ASC for the reverse sorting.